# Is complicity not a antonym of simplicity?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, antonyms

etymonline says

> simplicity (n.)
>
> late 14c., "singleness of nature, unity,
> indivisibility; immutability," from Old French simplicite (12c.,
> Modern French simplicité), from Latin simplicitatem (nominative
> simplicitas) "state of being simple, frankness, openness, artlessness,
> candor, directness," from simplex (genitive simplicis) "simple" (see
> simplex).
>
> The sense of "ignorance" is from c. 1400; that of "simplicity of
> expression, plainness of style" is by early 15c. Middle English also
> had simplesse, from French, and compare simpleness. The earliest was
> simplete, "lack of ostentation," c. 1200, from Old French.
>
> also from late 14c.

and

> complicity (n.)
>
> "the state of being an accomplice, partnership in wrongdoing or an
> objectionable act," 1650s, from French complicité, from Old French
> complice "accomplice, comrade, companion" (14c.), from Late Latin
> complicem, accusative of complex "partner, confederate," from Latin
> complicare "to fold together," from com "with, together" (see com-) +
> plicare "to fold, weave" (from PIE root *plek- "to plait"). Compare
> accomplice.
>
> also from 1650s

and W-M says:

> simplicity noun
>
> 1: the state of being simple, uncomplicated, or uncompounded
>
> 2a: lack of subtlety or penetration : INNOCENCE, NAIVETÉ
>
> b: FOLLY, SILLINESS
>
> 3: freedom from pretense or guile : CANDOR
>
> 4a: directness of expression : CLARITY
>
> b: restraint in ornamentation : AUSTERITY

and

> complicity noun
>
> 1: association or participation in or as if in a wrongful act
>
> 2: an instance of complicity

Are all the meanings of complicity negative?

Is it not an antonym of simplicity?

What would be a good antonym of simplicity?

Comment: No.  As your dictionary quotes show, the two words are not antonyms.  Ignore the etymology (a diversion not the true meaning). A thesaurus will give various antonyms, but you'll need to specify which sense of "simplicity" you mean.  Vote to close as there is nothing that is answerable, which isn't already answered in the question.

Comment: The best antonym in my opinion is to share some root or suffix. So it looks like complexity is the best one for simplicity.  Why makes complicity not easy to guess its meaning, by sharing the same suffix with simplicity?

Comment: The "best" antonym is the word with the opposite sense.  But "simplicity" has multiple senses.  So there are multiple "best" antonym.  The two words share an ending  - so what?  What makes "complicity" not easy to guess is that it means "in association with" and doesn't mean "complexity".  There is no point asking "why doesn't it mean complexity?" English is a natural language and words don't always mean what you want them to mean.

Comment: Some words resemble each other accidentally. This happens in all languages. Don't get angry with English for it.

Comment: @StuartF where did I show anger?

Answer (score 4):

No.

You're probably thinking of the root words '*simple*' and '*complex*', which come from Latin words that mean *comprising of one thing*, and *comprising of many things* respectively.

'Simplicity' has roots in the Latin *simplex*, but 'complicity' comes from the Old French '*complice*', meaning 'partner', and is where we also get the word 'accomplice' from. *Complicity* means *the condition of being involved with others in an activity*, so the two words you are asking about are not antonyms and have no real relationship with each other.

The true antonym of *simplicity* is *complexity* - the word derived from the Latin antonym.